# python strings concatenated of upper case alphabets

Tags: sails.js

Accept two strings 'string1' and 'string2' as an input from the user. Generate a resultant string, such that it is a concatenated string of all upper case alphabets from both the strings in the order they appear. Print the actual and the resultant strings in python

Comment: Show what you already tried

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = input("Enter a string: ")
string2 = input("Enter another string: ")
result = ""
for i in string1:
    if (i.isupper()):
        result = result + i
for i in string2:
    if (i.isupper()):
        result = result + i
print("String1: " + string1)
print("String2: " + string2)
print(result)
```